# SQL Server computed column formula for division and multiplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I'm setting the formula for a computed column in SQL server design mode. I have a column `Cost` and a column `commission`.

The column `commission` is stored as a whole number and should be divided by 100 to be percent.

My current column is `cost_with_commission` and should be calculated as below:

```
cost_with_commission = Cost * (1 + (commission / 100))
```

Can anyone help me with the syntax? I tried this and it was wrong:

```
(isnull([Cost], (0)) + ((1) + (isnull([commission], (0)) / (100))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your whole number to allow decimals and change the plus to multiply.

```
Declare @commission Int = 18
Declare @cost Float = 100.50

Select (isnull(@Cost,(0)) * ((1)+(isnull(Cast(@commission As Float),(0))/(100))))
```

Result:

```
118.59
```

Answer (score 1):

First, pay attention to integer division.  Second, you have no danger of a divide by 0.

So:

```
cost_with_commission = Cost * (1 + coalesce(commission, 0) / 100.0))
```